# Is "Adding up to the many times they have." after this sentence correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

> The ministers voted to increase their income. Adding up to the many times they have.

"...the many times they have VOTED TO INCREASE THEIR INCOME"?

is that it?

Can we end sentences that way?

Comment: Please provide the source of the quote  (my google finds nothing)

Answer (score 0):

In general, yes, when a past participle complement of "to have" is being repeated, then often we can omit the second instance when it is obvious. For example:

> I've visited Paris, just as you have.

However, your sentence doesn't make sense because "adding up" doesn't seem to be used correctly here. Also, your second "sentence" is really a fragment. This would be better:

> The ministers voted to increase their income, adding to the great number of times that they have.

However, this is still not so good, because the position of the implied verb (at the end of the sentence) is very far from its first instance ("voted"), while two other verbs ("to increase" and "adding") intervene. It is therefore not so easy for the reader to figure out what is meant. I would use a "pro-verb" to help the reader understand the intended structure:

> The ministers voted to increase their income, adding to the great number of times that they have done so.

Comment: thank you. I don't get: " because the position of the implied verb (at the end of the sentence) is very far from its first instance ("voted")" part. Is that the of in "of times that they have."???

Comment: @Lynerapintcho Here is the sentence with the implied verb (and its dependent elements) written out: "The ministers voted to increase their income, adding to the great number of times that they have voted to increase their income." The second instance of "voted" is far from the first, so if it is omitted, then a reader might not easily recognize that that is what is supposed to go there.